# How can the top padding be removed from Android JetPack Compose ModalBottomSheetLayout?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, bottom-sheet

I have tried for a few hours without success to remove the top padding from the Compose ModalBottomSheetLayout.

I tried debugging through the internal material classes to trace where the padding is being set and can't for the life of me work it out!

I want to add a background image which completely fills the ModalBottomSheetLayout right up to and including the rounded corners but clipped by them. Even if I remove the rounded corners (see pic) the issue remains with the extra padding above the sheetContent.

I have added an image with some background colors showing the issue. The blue bar is the top (extra unknown padding) of the bottom sheet opened at HalfExpanded state.

[image]

Another example with the rounded corners:

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using the `sheetBackgroundColor` value on `ModalBottomSheetLayout`? Then both would be the same color.

Comment: Yes @ianhanniballake I was just using the colors to figure out where the padding is coming from and to show it here more clearly. What I really want is to fill the sheet background completely with an image and remove the padding. Since writing the post I found a workaround by making the sheet color transparent and putting a rounded corner shape on the content. It's not nice and the padding is still there but it's all I've got so far :( Thanks

Comment: @ianhanniballake Being able to set this value would be nice. It would allow implementing [a drag handle as demonstrated in the material design guideline](https://m3.material.io/components/bottom-sheets/specs). The drag handle sits too low otherwise.